# Different behaviour in AJAX call in browser and "Copy as cURL"

Tags: php, ajax, curl, shopware

The general setting:

In a Shopware project I'm trying to get a new version of a payment plugin up and running. One specific payment method got a new API and doesn't work on our staging environment. (Locally no problem) After debugging for some time, I could break down the problem to an AJAX call that is supposed to store an authorizationToken it got from the payment service to the session on the server.

This AJAX call shows a super strange behaviour: When initiated by the browser through the page's JavaScript, the call doesn't work as expected. The sent token isn't stored in the REDIS store and I don't find any response body (which is supposed to contain debug output). I get a 200 response code anyway. What vexes me most is the fact that, when I use the developer's tools' "Copy as cURL" function and paste it into my commandline or e.g. the Insomnia GUI-client, everything works as expected. Session value stored. Debug output received.

So my actual question is:
How can a request from the browser be different from one made by curl or Insomnia when I made sure they use the exact same parameters and headers by copying them from the dev tools?
Am I barking up the wrong tree and it's just a timing issue? (Then the question of how such a request could fail because of a bad timing arises.)

I'm trying to provide some more background information:
The controller code is super simple (yeah, the "protected" looks strange indeed, seems to be some shopware special feature that makes it work at all)

```
protected function storeAuthorizationTokenAction()
    {
        $this->container->get('front')->Plugins()->ViewRenderer()->setNoRender();

        $token = $this->request->getParam('authorizationToken');

        $this->session->offsetSet('mopt_klarna_authorization_token', $token);
    }
```

Shopware Version: 5.4.3,
Payment Plugin (where this code is from): PayOne 4.3.1
This is the curl request. originally it was supposed to be a POST, one debugging attempt was to make it a GET. It doesn't change the behaviour, though. cURL works, original request in browser doesn't.

```
curl 'https://<domain>/de/MoptAjaxPayone/storeAuthorizationToken?authorizationToken=20ae061a-b8cd-2008-a7f9-84e94ca71523' \
  -H 'authority: <domain>' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'x-csrf-token: KgDxrkUB3KkbVOHWSwEOUWVIWpRHJL' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://<domain>/de/checkout/shippingPayment/sTarget/checkout' \
  -H 'accept-language: de,da;q=0.9,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6' \
  -H 'cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1339746099.1600161423; _gid=GA1.2.787319341.1603793583; x-ua-device=desktop; __utmzz=utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)|utmccn=(not set); __utmzzses=1; _fbp=fb.1.1603793583917.1305294048; __csrf_token-1=KgDxrkUB3KkbVOHWSwEOUWVIWpRHJL; scarab.visitor=%2247EEF371B0831C41%22; BasketToken_SfXEGBXzFnFsiZY8z4mKdqvDl8BICC6B=BgSmkYYV9xE3N56RIumHFJi6YvNaOz8FfeymjKCJZHZKJULmQp; shopSelected=true; layerLanguage=de; layerCountry=2; BasketToken_gLjjyccOBRSrepPczTlbSRAbfmSrBh2p=YvCgZrhAAINEJkcJppJ3mk4eykbjSSsiExGh5dIK3t1ZwZzJu2; gender=/de/damen; scarab.mayAdd=%5B%7B%22i%22%3A%224333421%2520100%252034%22%7D%2C%7B%22i%22%3A%226368511%2520122%252046%22%7D%2C%7B%22i%22%3A%224331722%2520101%252032%22%7D%5D; nocache=detail-1%2C+checkout-1; session-1=glntj79ep8si7pah9c4fjfnpk7; slt=a2527090-a6e8-4cbd-83df-da52afd4bd0f.1; BasketToken_0D94YPGBB6uBsFTn6pegR4wpilYwkIiO=GRlVSQ8XqTBKW7o1wy0l3EVBXRvcPnCmQfwddxa9Dwygm8IPC1; x-cache-context-hash=31b937a0b05d5618b106ef9e865d2507e7771077; _gat_UA-48161381-13=1; _uetsid=a3b0cc00177211ebbd7c65d866bae873; _uetvid=3d0f5d4a49d80e3f35cd03b932b1ec0c' \
  --compressed
```

Let me know if I can provide any further information.

Comment: Although I don't have an answer for your overall problem, I can tell you at least why sometimes AJAX doesn't behave the same as curl. Because AJAX runs from within a browser, it is bound to the browser's security requirements including CORS, same-origin policies, cookie rules, etc. curl, on the other hand, isn't really bound by anything except the raw protocol itself and is free to do whatever it wants.

Comment: @ChrisHaas
Yep, sure. But I would say that all of these requirements shouldn't be a problem. 
1. I'm on the exact same domain
2. The browser doesn't issue any warnings
3. The server behaviour is different.
4. Every other request from that same tested PAYMENT plugin works as expected. (So how come we run into said requirement problems with this one, on the same page,  a few secons earlier)
THX anyway, I'm grateful for any ideas and maybe if I think a bit more, about your idea, I come closer to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, here is my answer:

The requests have been cancelled by the browser due to FORM SUBMISSION. Note the different behaviour between browsers:
Firefox pointed me in the right direction because it doesn't even try to wait for the answer. The moment the form is submitted, the browser cancels the request. On the serverside, in this case nginx, logs a 499. FF dev tools DON'T show a response code at all.
Chrome on the other hand, just doesn't wait for the answer, but shows a 200 OK response without a body.

The solution is to make the ajax request synchronous.

Comment: The answer is not make it synchronous... The answer is cancel the form submission. If you need to submit the form, when you get the call back submit the form with JavaScript.

Comment: @epascarello Yep, maybe you're right. But in my special case the plugin developer needs to fix it anyway on their side. I just needed it to work quickly. Their solution which will be released in a few weeks, seems to be making it synchronous. I don't know if that is a bad sign :(